# How can I correct the "duplicate" Count on a INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have a duplicated `COUNT` on this query:

```
SELECT
DATE(dia.DTM) AS 'Dia',
COUNT(temp.TMP) AS 'Index'
FROM dados_meteo dia
INNER JOIN dados_meteo temp
ON temp.DTM = dia.DTM
AND temp.TMP BETWEEN 20 AND 30
WHERE dia.POM = 'Alcobaca'
GROUP BY DATE(dia.DTM)
```

Comment: Why do you join dados_meteo to itself?

Comment: I have to assure that even when the day only have temp bellow 20, I have a count = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly (please describe exacly what you want the query to do), you'll get what you want by changing `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Or by this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(dia.DTM) AS 'Dia',
    SUM(dia.TMP BETWEEN 20 AND 30) AS 'Index'
FROM dados_meteo dia
WHERE dia.POM = 'Alcobaca'
GROUP BY DATE(dia.DTM)
```

What the above query is actually doing is this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(dia.DTM) AS 'Dia',
    COUNT( CASE WHEN dia.TMP BETWEEN 20 AND 30
                THEN 'yes'
                ELSE NULL
           END )
      AS 'Index'
FROM dados_meteo dia
WHERE dia.POM = 'Alcobaca'
GROUP BY DATE(dia.DTM)
```

---

After the comments, here's a slight modification:

```
SELECT
    DATE(dia.DTM) AS 'Dia',
    CASE WHEN SUM(dia.TMP BETWEEN 20 AND 30) >= 24
         THEN 20
         ELSE -10
    END AS 'Index'
FROM dados_meteo dia
WHERE dia.POM = 'Alcobaca'
GROUP BY DATE(dia.DTM)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a table with 96 temp records per day (15 min periods). When there are more than 6 hours with temperature between 20 and 30 I want that the query give me a column with day and a column with 20. Else I need the day and -10.

Comment: My initial "system" was
SELECT
DATE(DTM) AS 'Dia',
CASE 
WHEN ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4)>=6 THEN '20'
WHEN ROUND(COUNT(TMP)/4)<6 THEN '-10'
END
AS 'Index'
FROM dados_meteo
WHERE TMP>=20 AND TMP<=30/* AND POM = '[VARIABLE]'*/
GROUP BY DATE(DTM)

But I don't get all the days...

Comment: I guess it's working. Will the JOIN solution no longer needded?

Comment: @Hugo: See my updated answer. The count of 24 is not on consecutive temperature measurements though. That would require more complex query. Now, it just counts if there `24` or more measurements with tmp `20 <= TMP <= 30`.

Comment: I would like also to understand why you use SUM instead of COUNT.

Comment: You can use either of these. The `SUM` way works only in MySQL because `True` is evaluated as `1` and `False` as `0`.

Comment: I see. You SUM the logical value of the expression, not the temperature value.

Comment: @Hugo: Exactly. As a side note, I've seen some other questions you have posted and it seems that this (and other queries you run) would be faster if you had the `DTM` stored in two separate fields for `m_date` and `m_time` and had an index on `m_date` or `(m_date, m_time)` . Keep that in mind for when the table will have many rows and it becomes slow.

Comment: @ypercube: May I send you my data files in order to give me your opinion?

Comment: @Hugo: I suppose this doesn't violate any site policy, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the query but I would really suggest having a separate calendar table:

```
select "Dia", "Index"
from
    (select distinct date(dia.dtm) calendar_date
    from dados_meteo) calendar left outer join
    (select date(dtm) as "Dia", count(tmp) as "Index"
    from dados_meteo
    where pom = 'Alcobaca' and tmp between 20 and 30
    group by date(dtm)) temp on calendar.calendar_date = "Dia"
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn´t give me 0 when we only have temp bellow 20

Comment: What is the exact output? Are you getting list of locations and nulls in the "Index" column? Try using ifnull() or coalesce() in that case.

Comment: No I don't. That's the problem. When the day only have records bellow 20, It is missing. How can I use if null() or coalesce() in the solution that you give me?

Comment: You'd have to get a list of dates somehow and left outer join it to the count of daily measurements where temperature falls into the desired range. If the table is big and you need to run such daily counts frequently, you might consider adding a separate field for the date. If the table is really big (millions of records), you might consider creating a table for the dates in the range you might ever want to query.